# How to get acronyms description with lowercase letters within text, but uppercase letters at the acronyms list?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Using glossaries package, I would like to define acronyms in the text using lowercase letters as follows:
sample acronym (SA)
degrees of freedom (DOF)
While recurrences will be displayed as:
SA
DOF

However, at the acronyms list, I would like it to appear with uppercase letters as:
SA - Sample Acronym
DOF - Degrees of Freedom

A simple example should look like this:
[image]

Using the following code, I can't get it right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description=a sample entry}

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{Sample Acronym}
\newacronym{dof}{DOF}{Degrees of Freedom}

\begin{document}

This is a \gls{sample}. And this is a \gls{sa}, while another one will be \gls{dof}.
Recurrences are \gls{sa} and \gls{dof}.

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\printglossary

\printglossary[type=acronym,style = super]
\end{document}
```

The results are:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `glossaries-extra`, you can just set the `glossdesc` attribute.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{glossdesc}{title}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,description=a sample entry}

\newabbreviation{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}
\newabbreviation{dof}{DOF}{degrees {}of freedom}

\begin{document}

This is a \gls{sample}. And this is a \gls{sa}, while another one will be \gls{dof}.
Recurrences are \gls{sa} and \gls{dof}.

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\printglossary

\printglossary[type=abbreviations, style=super]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Works great!
Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, you can show that by upvoting (the up arrow to the left of the answer) and maybe accepting it (the tick mark below). This shows your appreciation to the answerer and marks your question as answered in the system.